# Partition excisting table on a specific ID

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad, database-partitioning

I have an Oracle SQL question.

I need to partition a existing table (filled with data) on a specific ID. I did some research but I don't see how.
When I generate a script from a already made partitioned table (In toad) I get this output:

```
PARTITION BY LIST (ID)
(  
  PARTITION SAMPLE_TABLE_6226563032 VALUES (6226563032)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE samplespace
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION SAMPLE_TABLE_6164428638 VALUES (6164428638)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE samplespace
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION SAMPLE_TABLE_6164428803 VALUES (6164428803)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE samplespace
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
```

You can see there is a partition for each ID and this for 100+ IDS/records.

Does anybody know a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1 (added answer here for readability):

Thanks for the answer, Wernfried!
Looking into it as we speak.
But I'm also searching for the partition statement. Because it has to be a list but in all examples when they do a list partition they add hardcoded values. Like this:

`PARTITION BY LIST (LOC_CODE) 
(
PARTITION GRABB VALUES ('IND'),
PARTITION CNILX VALUES ('NZ'),
PARTITION NOAAS VALUES ('SL'),
PARTITION SGIND VALUES ('RSA'),
PARTITION SAARA VALUES ('PAK'),
PARTITION MYABB VALUES ('USA')
)`

While it actually has to be dynamic (for every ID).

EDIT2:
I did this:

`partition by range (id)
interval (1)
 (PARTITION "P0" VALUES LESS THAN (1))
 TABLESPACE "TABLESPAXE"
;`

But when i want to insert some data

`insert into partitioned_table  select * from original_table  where id=123456 ;`

It throws an exception:

`"ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions"`

So i guess 12C databases don't automatically create partitions on insert? or am i wrong?

Comment: Is there s specific reason to create 100+ partitions on a single table? It must be a really huge table.

Comment: It's needed for the company this db is meant for

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Oracle PL/SQL Package [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_redefi.htm#CBBJJAIF), there you can redefine existing tables, e.g. a non-partitioned table to a partitioned table (even without application downtimes).

Note, you need twice the table size free on your table space because DBMS_REDEFINITION creates a copy of your "old" table in case you have to make a rollback.

Comment: Thanks!
Looking into it as we speak.
But I'm also searching for the partition statement. Because it has to be a list but in all examples when they do a list partition they add hardcoded values. Like this:

`PARTITION BY LIST (LOC_CODE) 
(
PARTITION GRABB VALUES ('IND'),
PARTITION CNILX VALUES ('NZ'),
PARTITION NOAAS VALUES ('SL'),
PARTITION SGIND VALUES ('RSA'),
PARTITION SAARA VALUES ('PAK'),
PARTITION MYABB VALUES ('USA')
)`

While it actually has to be dynamic (for every ID).

Comment: What about RANGE partitions? Something like `partition by range(ID) Interval  (1)`

Comment: Yup did it like this
`partition by range (id)
interval (1)
 (PARTITION "P0" VALUES LESS THAN (1))
 TABLESPACE "TABLESPAXE"
;`
But when i want to insert some data
`insert into partitioned_table  select * from original_table  where id=123456 ;`
It throws an exception: "ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions"

So i guess 12C databases don't automatically create partitions on insert? or am i wrong?

Comment: No, it is the purpose of `INTERVAL` partitions that they are created automatically. The error meas: Too many partitions - which let me to repeat my earlier comment: "Why do you like to create so many partitions on a single table?" It seems to be useless.

Comment: What is your least number of `ID`. If you put `VALUES LESS THAN (1)` and `INTERVAL (1)` and the least value is `6226563032` (as in your example), I assume Oracle tries to create 6226563032(**!!!**) partitions.

Comment: yup just found out myself too. I don't need that many more I just needed a partition for id=6226563032 and one for id=789421236 (pure random). But now i see he creates the whole interval so it's not what I needed